# Automated FTP Script Not Finding Source Directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, directory, ftp

How could I modify the script below to include the source directory so that it will know which location to retrieve the files required for transfer?

I have a bash script for the purpose of automatically transferring files to a remote server, which occurs once a week.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=sftp.mydomain.com  
USER=user           
PASS=pass          

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
$USER $PASS
cd /d D:\destination\directory
put file1.gz
put file2.gz
put file3.gz

bye

EOF
```

Files 1-3 are all in source/directory, so I'd like to transfer all files from source/directory to the destination path specified above.

However, I believed that because the script is running on the source VM, that I wouldn't need to specify a directory since the script could simply pull it from any folder (rookie mistake, I understand).

Alternatively: is there an easier way to use ftp for an entire directory as opposed to simply listing the entire content of the folder?

Comment: Given that the target host is named `sftp` might it be that you could use an `ssh`-based protocol instead of the ancient and insecure `ftp`? If this is the case you can look at commands using `sftp` such as `sftp` and `lftp`, and even consider `scp` with certificates, which are very much easier to manage than unsecured passwords.

Comment: The `cd` command only takes a single argument, no?  To transfer the complete contents of a directory hierarchy using FTP, transfer it as a `tar` archive.

Comment: @roaima I have attempted to use scp and other ssh-layered attempts previously, but I was met with considerable resistance and a plethora of errors which I was unable to resolve - I resigned myself to a much simpler method; however, I have configured the ftp server to use tls certificates for some extra protection

Kusalananda - I have not attempted this, but I will try to do so - thank you

Comment: do you just need an `lcd` inside the ftp script, or a plain old `cd` before the `ftp`?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller As this is a remote server, I believe that cd would be the more appropriate option, but if you're able to convince me otherwise, I am open to any changes. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your reference to "files 1-3" (file{1..3}.gz), but then your request to "transfer all files from source to destination".  Do you want to explicitly list the files, or not?

Comment: I have some files in /source/directory on the host machine that I'd like to transfer to \destination\directory. Files 1-3 are simply placeholder names for the sake of helping people visualize the issue. Please let me know if this has clarified the issue.

Comment: If you want to transfer all the files, then I would just say that, and remove any mention of specific files.  If you didn't know the "mput" command, just put comments there saying "# some command to put all the files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change which directory the `ftp` process sees as the source, either `cd` there beforehand or `lcd` there within:

1.

```
cd /source/directory
ftp ...
```

2.

```
ftp ...
lcd /source/directory
...
```

[`lcd` (from `man ftp`)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) is short for `local change directory`; it will:

> Change the working directory on the local machine.

"Local" here means the system that you ran `ftp` from.

To put all files from the current local directory to the current remote directory in ftp, use:

```
prompt
mput *
```

The `prompt` FTP command disabled interactive prompting during "multiple" operations, such as `mget` or `mput`. Quoting from the [FTP man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) (or see your local `man ftp`):

> Interactive prompting occurs during multiple file transfers to allow the user to selectively retrieve or store files.